# How do I use the pipe command to display attributes in a file?

Tags: linux, pipe

I'm currently making a shell program and I want to display the total amount of bytes in a specific file using the pipe command. I know that the pipe command takes whatever is on the left side and gives it to the right as input. (Assuming you are in the directory the file is in)

I know that the command (`wc -c`) displays the number of bytes in a file but I'm not sure how to pipe it. What I've tried was:

```
ls fileName.sh | wc -c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wc` takes the filename as *argument*, not as *input*. Try this:

```
wc -c fileName.sh
```

The `wc` program takes multiple arguments. You can do this to apply it to all entries in the current working directory:

```
wc -c $(ls)
```

Another approach is to use `xargs` to convert input to arguments:

```
ls | xargs wc -c
```

You may need to use a more complex line if you have spaces in your filenames. `ls` can output a single file per line, and `xargs` can be told to split only on `\n`:

```
ls -1 | xargs -d '\n' wc -c
```

If you prefer to use `find` instead of `ls` (a more powerful tool), the `-print0` option for `find` plays along with the `-0` option to `xargs`.